# Reverse 3(DES) key for decryption with encryption function

Tags: encryption, 3des

Is it possible to derive reverse key for use as opposite function in 3DES algorithm. Idea is that the key that is used for encryption will be doing decryption and vice versa.

```
encrypt(3des_key, data) == decrypt(3des_reverse_key,data)
decrypt(3des_key, data) == encrypt(3des_reverse_key,data)
```

Of course as 3DES is just 3 time DES function, the question is transparently generalised to DES algorithm so:

```
encrypt(des_key, data) == decrypt(des_reverse_key,data)
decrypt(des_key, data) == encrypt(des_reverse_key,data)
```

If exists such a reverse key function that those two statements are true extending this function for use in 3des is just a simple displacement of key sectors.

Comment: If you'd care to read up on [DES](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_Encryption_Standard), you should be aware of the existence of the semi-weak keys: "There are also six pairs of semi-weak keys. Encryption with one of the pair of semiweak keys, K_1, operates identically to decryption with the other, K_2" Since these keys are explicitly called out and exhibit exactly the property you're looking for, you should be able to realise that the vast majority of keys (that are neither weak nor semi-weak) do not have this property.

Comment: Tha was exactly what I was looking for. I read this page but such a details are easy to be missed, especially if you are looking for some specific property. Thank you for pointing it.